# The Lebesgue Theory basic Application , get stuck

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, lebesgue-integral

Ok, I am working on a very easy question but I get stuck when I trying to justify my answer.

I know that, in order to use Lebesgue's dominated Convergence Theorem, there are two conditions that we need to satisfy:

First, ${\displaystyle \ f_n}$ need to be functions on $\mathbb{R}$ converging pointwise to a limit${\displaystyle \ f}$

Second, there must be a function ${\displaystyle \ g}$ with finite integral such that each |${\displaystyle \ f_n}$| ${\leqslant}$${\displaystyle \ g}$, then:
${\displaystyle \int \lim f_n\,dx}={\lim\displaystyle \int f_n\,dx}$

Now, I need to compute ${\displaystyle \lim _{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_1^2 \! {x^{2-\sin(nx)/n}} \, \mathrm{d} x}$.   I am almost positive that it's the integration of ${\displaystyle \ {x^2}}$ over the interval $[1,2]$.

My question is, how do I justify this? I tried to prove it is pointwise convergence but failed to find a good N to do the job.

And again, I apologize if this is a too-easy question for most of folks here, but I'd appreciate if you can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $|\sin(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x$, we have
$$0\leq2-\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}\leq 2+\frac{|\sin(nx)|}{n}\leq 3\mbox{ for all }x\in [1,2]\mbox{ and }n\geq 1.$$
This implies that 
$$\Big|x^{2-\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}}\Big|=x^{2-\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}}\leq x^3\mbox{ for all }x\in [1,2].$$
Note that $x^3$ is integrable on $[1,2]$ since $\int_1^2x^3dx=\frac{2^4-1}{4}<\infty$. Therefore, we can apply Lebesgue's dominated Convergence Theorem to conclude that 
$$\tag{1}\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^2x^{2-\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}}dx=\int_1^2\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{2-\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}}dx.$$
Once again, since $|\sin(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x$, we have
$$0\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|\sin(nx)|}{n}\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$$
which implies that $$\tag{2}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}=0\mbox{ for all }x\in[1,2].$$
Putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together, we obtain
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^2x^{2-\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}}dx=\int_1^2\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{2-\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}}dx=\int_1^2x^{2-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}}dx
=\int_1^2x^{2}dx=\frac{2^3-1}{3}=\frac{7}{3}.$$

Comment: Ugh! People are smart! I worked with sin(nx)/n directly and complaining the whole thing is too complicated to compute... But use x^3 is not something quite exceptional; there are "tricks" that I need to get familiar with. Haha... Thanks a lot @Paul, and also for these edits! My first time use Latex, much more to learn :)

Comment: You did a good job even it's your first time using Latex. Just keep practicing and you will get familiar with it.